# Does MtouchSdkVersion setting affect what version of iOS we can run on?

Tags: xamarin.ios

When deploying an existing Xamarin forms proj from Visual Studio I was getting errors like "Failed to load AOT module ‘System.Net.Http’ while running in aot-only mode".  This had worked in the past, it seemed Xcode had recently updated before I hit the problem.  I found I was able to get the project deploying by changing the csproj entry 10.0 to 10.3.  It looks like I could change this setting and everyone would be ok if they also had updated xcode.

My concern is:  Does this change what versions of iOS the application can support?  Would it have any other surprises when deployed to the apple store?

One thing I don't understand is I am the only person seeing this issue.  Another developer is able to deploy to an iOS device (iPad instead of an iPhone) that also has the latest version of iOS without problems.  Running “xcodebuild -version” shows we have the same version of xcode installed (8.3.1) and running “xcodebuild -showsdks” shows we have the same iOS sdk available (iOS 10.3).

Comment: related question: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/94162/mtouchsdkversion-risks-of-running-different-versions/

Answer (score 0):

There is some good documentation on the iOS SDK version: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Overview/overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002001-BABEBGCF

1. You can build against a higher version of the SDK and run against lower versions of iOS.
2. Building against different versions of the iOS SDK can cause differences in behavior, these may show as regressions in your application.